# Embeding a video from youtube into HTML5

Tags: html, video, youtube

I have tried every method that I've read about to embed a youtube video into my HTML5, but it will not work in any browser.  The best I get is a square that says the website cannot be found.  I've tried using the old embed code, I've tried using the iframe...I've also tried using the new video tag...I've dumped each one of the codes into their own separate part (meaning not contained in a div or anything like that)...The only thing that it is contained in is the body itself...I've also tried the opposite by putting all three of these methods in some sort of container like a div.  Not that being in one or not being in one should affect it's playability, but I'm trying everything...I don't understand why it just won't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't showing what you tried that didn't work, but I'm feeling psychic today so here's a wild stab:

YouTube is currently giving out embed links that look like this:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360"      
  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/sLAEg5aTXAE?feature=player_detailpage"
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What's unusual about this is that the URL -- in the "src" attribute of the IFrame tag -- does not specify a protocol.

The format of the src attribute above is a type of relative URL, called a *protocol-relative URL*, that allows the embed tag to work regardless of whether your page is being accessed with an http:// or https:// protocol.  (You aren't allowed to mix these in a single page)

However -- and I'm guessing this is where you're going wrong -- if you open an HTML5 file locally, and not through a web server, it has a file:// URL.  Because relative URLs -- including this oddball protocol-relative URL -- always take their unspecified bits from the current page location, the full URL that is being calculated is invalid:

file://www.youtube.com/embed/sLAEg5aTXAE?feature=player_detailpage

To fix, just change the src attribute to specify the protocol, changing the relative URL into an absolute URL that works from a page served with both file:// and http:// protocols.

```
<iframe width="640" height="360"      
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sLAEg5aTXAE?feature=player_detailpage"
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The drawback is that you can't put this on a page being delivered over https.

In the longer term you should get in the habit of testing from a real web server instead of a file URL.  For a locally-installed test server, WAMP/MAMP is an easy and popular choice.

Comment: Thank you my friend, you are spot on. That's exactly what I was doing.  I apologize for posting a description rather than code, I'm new to this game.  It hadn't even occurred to me that it was a relative link.  I was also unaware of the http/https conflict.  As well, I was unaware that there was a site that I could test my page as if it were on a server.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome, @user2808962!  Glad to hear this helped.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, WAMP is not a site.  It's a program (actually a bundle of software) that you can install on your system.  When it's running, it makes your computer a web server.